# Changed root's shell to non-existing path

Tags: shell, freebsd, root

I just made a bit of a mistake:

- Fresh install of FreeBSD 8.2
- logged in as root
- installed bash from ports
- created users, setting bash as shell
- `vipw` (edit passwd file)
- changed root's shell from `/bin/csh` to `/bin/bash`
- logged out
- log in as root
- WRONG!!

As you probably guessed, bash shell is not placed in /bin :( Pretty dumb mistake!

Now I can't login as root. 
I can login as my wheel user, but can't `vipw`.

Tried the following without luck:

- Reboot to single user, `/rescue/vi /etc/passwd`
- Login as wheel user, `su -m`

So how do i change the root shell back to `/bin/csh` ?

I could just re-install - but i'd rather learn some new stuff!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Boot into single user mode and then:

```
mount -w /
vipw
```

Change path to `/usr/local/bin/bash`

```
exit
```

Comment: I have edited your answer, should be visible once it is peer reviewed; so SF tells me. Thank you very much, it helped me in the right direction followed by this article http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-freebsd-reset-recover-root-password.html

Answer (score 3):

Just a tip...
After the first login as root, i change the toor password.
This way, even with data corruption/disk or partition lost, I have a user with privileges and 2 différents shells.

Comment: I certainly will do that after this little mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a live CD/DVD of some kind. (Gentoo is a good choice.) Just mount the drive, and edit the /etc/passwd file.

Comment: +1 for simple and effective fix

Comment: Great tip, thank you for your help. Didn't use it this time, but could come in handy.

Comment: How is Gentoo a "good choice"?! The FreeBSD CD/DVD has an emergency shell, which can at least read the file system...

Answer (score 2):

Can you `su` (without `-`) ?

If not, maybe `sudo -u root /usr/bin/bash` could work?

Otherwise, boot from CD, mount the root file system, change the `etc/passwd` file on the root file system, sync, umount, reboot.

Comment: Can't su, can't sudo (not installed), can't install sudo

Answer (score 0):

The correct command for single user mode is:

```
mount -u -rw /
mount -a -t ufs
```

then just do: chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash root

Comment: I have corrected the single user answer. Are you sure that the -r switch should be there? According to FreeBSD `man mount` this toggles read-only, and the w switch is read and write. A bit confusing.

Comment: Chris S: specifically, the mount -a -t ufs means, ONLY mount all file systems of type UFS, ie, don't mount nfs, ntfs, smb etc file systems. since these won't work in single user mode.

Answer (score 0):

I've just done exactly the same on a Synology Diskstation - I assumed /bin/bash was available when hurriedly changing the root shell. Doh.

I used the -s option of su when logged in as admin to force a shell:

```
-s, --shell=SHELL            run SHELL if /etc/shells allows it
```

That is:

```
su -s /bin/ash
```

Phew.

Comment: This only works if you can login as a user in the Wheel group. The Question didn't have such a user. Your case really isn't the same...

Comment: OP says: "...I can login as my wheel user..."

Answer (score -1):

Try to modify grub boot string during boot so, that it couldn't find the kernel. grub will drop you to busybox. It has a built-in vi editor. Mount, edit and reboot.

Comment: No grub (hungry now)

Comment: -1 FreeBSD doesn't use Grub.